# How to capture video in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm building application that runs video, and  i want to capture the screen of my application while the video is running,
My problem is that the code I wrote does not capture the video, it takes a screenshot that does not include the video,
I need help how to do it correctly?, Code of Xamarin C#

this my code:

```
var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync();
var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync();
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a screen recorder?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this function on native platform with [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/)

On android, you can use Mediarecorder:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#java

On IOS, you can use AVCaptureSession:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession?language=objc